# Extended APDU Format

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu, jcop

I am trying to send a extended APDU to my smartcard reader, but i keep getting

> 67 00 (Wrong Length)

My extended APU:

```
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
```

Breakdown of the APDU:

```
CLA: 0x00
INS: 0xA4
P1 : 0x01
P2 : 0x02
LC : 0x00 0x01 0x04 (3 Bytes long)
Data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
```

I found information about extended APDU's here: https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/prognotes/extended-apdu-format.htm

And according to this reference my extended APDU should be alright. The LC field is 3 bytes because the data length exceeds 255 bytes (0x104 = 260 Bytes).

I cant find out what is wrong with this APDU, is the length not formatted right?

Comment: Is the last 0x00 part of the data or is this supposed to be Le field? If the latter then this needs to be 0x00 0x00. Other reason could be the reader does not support extended length.

Comment: Thank you, i will update the data. Yes i tried forcing T=1 protocol, but i get a error that my card uses T=0. Im now looking how to send extended APDU with T=0 (with envelope) but i can't find any examples of T=0 with envelope commands..

Comment: Why was this tagged Java Card? Extended length APDU's are not specific to Java Card. Did you implement an Applet possibly?

Comment: ISO 7816-3 on case3e with T=0: The command APDU shall be split into consecutive segments of less than 256 bytes transmitted into the data bytes of consecutive ENVELOPE command TPDUs. The absence of data bytes means “end of data string”. The first response from the card indicates if it supports ENVELOPE: 6D00 - No, 9000 - Yes. APDU ENVELOPE is CLA=00 INS=C2 P1P2=0000 Lc=xx Data=...

Comment: @nvf thank you, im trying to use T=1 now, the envelope is not supported on T=0 - so im going to look in the Applet Code and try to modify it so it does support extended APDU's.